# Facing error while debugging cucumber-nightwatch code in visual studio code

Tags: debugging, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch with cucumber, it works perfectly for me but when I started implementing debugging section, I stuck with the errors and not able to figure out how to solve it.

The error description is as below which I can see Debug console of VS code after running my launch.json

```
Debugger listening on [::]:46131
There was an error while starting the test runner:

Error: Cannot read source folder: {directory path}/examples/tests

at /Users/{directory path}/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/run.js:203:21 
at {directory path}/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/walk.js:97:18   
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

Below is my launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch"
        }
    ]
}
```

For a reference I have followed step from below url

```
http://mucsi96.github.io/nightwatch-cucumber/#debugging-with-visual-studio-code
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.